# Jquery click event animation

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery animation. I need to start the animation automatic when the site open.
but in this jQuery programmer put Click function. I want to remove the click function. But
after I remove the function all animation are stopped.

http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/curtains-opening-animation-with-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about this:

```
// when user clicks inside the container...  
$('.curtain_wrapper').click(function(){  

    //..animate the description div by changing it's left position to it's width (but as negative number)...  
    $(this).children('.description').animate({'left': -1*$(this).width()});  

    //...animate the 2 curtain images to width of 50px with duration of 2 seconds...  
    $(this).children('img.curtain').animate({ width: 50 },{duration: 2000});  

    //...show the content behind the curtains with fadeIn function (2 seconds)  
    $(this).children('.content').fadeIn(2000);  

});
```

Try changing the word `click`, for `each`:

```
$('.curtain_wrapper').each(...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add  `$('.curtain_wrapper').trigger('click');` to the actual code  !